# Db2 doesn't allow to update table, throws an error saying that operation is incomplete

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm getting an error when trying to update a table. The SQL statement is:

```
UPDATE dda_accounts SET TYPE_SK = TYPE_SK - 10 WHERE TYPE_SK > 9;
```

The error I get is:

```
SQL Error [57007]: Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table 
   "BANK_0002_TEST.DDA_ACCOUNTS".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57007, DRIVER=4.27.25
```

SQLSTATE `57007` says that there's something incomplete after an ALTER TABLE was executed.

I found [this resolution](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005pgi6lCAA/why-am-i-seeing-db2-sql-error-sqlcode668-sqlstate57016-or-sqlcode407-sqlstate23502-codes-on-iwd-startup-in-sco-v2301-and-how-do-i-resolve-this?language=en_US), but it's not clear if it can be fixed or the only way to recover the table is using a backup.

Running a select statement works, only the update fails. What is the way to fix this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `REORG` the table to recover, see this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001966.html) for details.

When you get an error like this, lookup the [SQL066N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic3.html#sql0668n) code with the reason code "7".

This shows:

> The table is in the reorg pending state. This can occur after an ALTER
> TABLE tatement containing a REORG-recommended operation.

Be aware the the previous alter table (that put the table into this state of reorg needed) might have happened quite some time ago, possibly without your knowledge.

If you lack the authorisation to perform `reorg table inplace "BANK_0002_TEST.DDA_ACCOUNTS"`  , then contact your DBA for assistance. The DBA may choose to also [reorg indexes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0070494.html) at the same time, and to perform `runstats` ([docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001980.html)) on the table following completion of the reorg, and to check whether anything else needs rebinding.

Comment: You could do that, i.e.  shell into the container, become the instance-owner (e.g. db2inst1), connect to the database, and run the reorg s and runstats.   You could __also__ (if your auth id has correct privileges) run the reorg via SQL with the ADMIN_CMD procedure as per documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023582.html

Comment: Ok, ADMIN_CMD is easier as by default the `db2` command is not configured in Docker